# Alternatives to Add-Printer, Remove-Printer etc. for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell, printing, windows-server-2008

I was given the Task of rewriting an old script into PowerShell from VBScript. This script basically just reads a line of a text file and installs the printer corresponding to that line, before removing it again, so that just the driver is installed.

This script gets executed every day on our virtual Citrix terminal servers, this way we can update drivers independently of the current released image.

Here's what the final script looks like:

```
# Variables
Param([string]$FileName)
$DriverList = Get-Content $FileName
$ComputerName = hostname
$LogFile = "C:\Windows\Logs\PrinterCreation.log"
$SeperatorL = "═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════"
$SeperatorS = "═══════════════════════════════════════════"
$StartDate = Get-Date -Format "dd.MMM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"

# Log Header
"$SeperatorL" > $LogFile
" ServerName:   $ComputerName" >> $LogFile
" DriverList:   $FileName" >> $LogFile
" StartTime:    $StartDate" >> $LogFile
"$SeperatorL" >> $LogFile
"" >> $LogFile
"Beginning driver instalation process:" >> $LogFile

# Process the "$DriverList" by installing each printer on the list and  deleting the connection afterwards
foreach ($line in $DriverList) {
    "$SeperatorL" >> $LogFile
    " Print driver Installation:    $line" >> $LogFile

    # Installing the printer
    try {
        Add-Printer -ConnectionName $line -ErrorAction Stop
        Start-Sleep -s 10

        # Deleting the Printer
        try {
            Remove-Printer -Name $line -ErrorAction Stop
            " Printer installation successfull." >> $LogFile
        } catch {
            " INSTALATION NOT COMPLETE:     Printer was installed but connection could not be removed!" >> $LogFile
        }
    } catch [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException] {
        " INSTALATION FAILED:           Printer driver cannot be found or does not exist!" >> $LogFile
    } finally {
        Start-Sleep -s 5
    }
}

# Log Footnote
$EndDate = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss"
"$SeperatorL" >> $LogFile
"" >> $LogFile
"Instalation process completed:" >> $LogFile
"$SeperatorS" >> $LogFile
" End Time: $EndDate" >> $LogFile
"$SeperatorS" >> $LogFile
```

It gets called like so: `.\scriptfilename.ps1 ".\Driverlist.txt"`

The driver list just consists of lines like these: `"\\spbdn140\KM_Universal_PCL"`

**The Problem in short**

When writing this script I hadn't realized that the printer management module only works from Win 8 and Server 2012 upwards. Our terminal servers are all running Server 2008.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do with the information available (the driver list) in PowerShell v3-4 on Server 2008?

Again, the end result should just be that the drivers are installed on the terminal servers just using the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so, the printer cmdlets are all for Win8/Server2008R2 and later. Unfortunately some cmdlets are OS specific and updating PowerShell does not include them.

However you could run a PowerShell script that called cscript.exe with what you needed done in PrnMngr.vbs etc.

[Here is a list of the vbscripts that you could use in place of the print management cmdlets.](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/blogs/chetcuti/command-line/windows-server-2008-printers-commands-45.html)